# How to put data driven gradient in a bar chart using d3.js

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, linear-gradients

I am trying to put gradients on a bar chart. All examples that I have seen allow us to put a single gradient/ same gradient over the whole chart.
eg: http://htmlasks.com/_getting_gradients_on_a_bar_chart
eg: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3970883

I have a setting in which:

1. there are multiple rectangles
2. each rectangle has a gradient
3. colors of the gradient vary based on data
4. offset percentages vary based on data

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the code that I am using. Not sure where I am going wrong.

this is how i call the function to create gradient 'give_gradient':

```
return give_gradient(d.card1,d.card2,d.card3,d.card1percent,d.card2percent,d.card3percent);
```

here d.card1, d.card2 and so on are the data elements used to define the gradient.

this is the function:

```
function give_gradient(color1,color2,color3,stop1,stop2,stop3){
    var gradient = svg.append("svg:defs")
    .append("svg:linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "gradient")
    .attr("x1", "0%")
    .attr("x2", "100%")
    .attr("y1", "0%")
    .attr("y2", "0%")
    .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

    gradient.append("svg:stop")
    .attr("offset", "0")
    .attr("stop-color", colorcode(color1))
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    gradient.append("svg:stop")
    .attr("offset", stop1)
    .attr("stop-color", colorcode(color1))
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    gradient.append("svg:stop")
    .attr("offset", stop1)
    .attr("stop-color", colorcode(color2))
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    gradient.append("svg:stop")
    .attr("offset", stop2)
    .attr("stop-color", colorcode(color2))
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    gradient.append("svg:stop")
    .attr("offset", stop2)
    .attr("stop-color", colorcode(color3))
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    gradient.append("svg:stop")
    .attr("offset", stop3)
    .attr("stop-color", colorcode(color3))
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    return "url(#gradient)";
}
```

What is the problem: the same gradient is coming for all rectangles irrespective of data in each. They are taking data of the first rectangle and getting repeated in all.

Comment: See [here](http://www.larsko.org/v/euca) for an example of data-dependent gradients.

Comment: You are assigning the same `id` to every `svg:linearGradient`.  How are you applying them to the `rects`?  If it's by `id`; it'll only use the last one.

Comment: You are right. Its by id. If I make ids of a different name each time, would you know how to change return "url(#gradient)" so it refers back to the right place.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the svg:stop usage here. Wouldn't you need to create a separate group for each bar?

Comment: It works like this as long as number of stops is same